# Expectation of number of voters who agrees with the proposed plan under the majority voting

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

This question raised in my research work and it is quite challenging for me. Consider a committee $D$ of $n$ voters, among these $n$ voters there are $n_1$ voters agreeing with the proposed plan, while the rest $n_0 = n - n_1$ voters disagree with the proposed plan. Now we randomly split these $n$ voters into K disjoint subsets of equal size, denoted by $D_1, ...,D_K$. Here $|D_i| = \frac{n}{K}$. In each subset (sub committee), all voters in this subset will perform majority voting to see if the plan is accepted or rejected inside this subcommittee. For example,  in sub committee $D_i$ if more people belong to $D_i$ vote for rejection than acceptance then the final decision of sub committee $D_i$ is rejection. Denote $0\leq m_1 \leq K$ represents the number of subcommittees who supports for the plan,  while the rest $m_0 = K- m_1$ votes agains the plan.

Compute the expectation of $m_1$ w.r.t randomness of splitting.

Comment: How would you deal with tied votes, either within or among subcommittees? Or is the setup assumed to have an odd number of total voters, of voters within each subcommittee, and of numbers of subcommittees?

Comment: You can make that assumption for simplicity.